# Changing block region on runtime (Drupal 6)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've got sidebar with bunch of blocks that wouldn't be rendered in mobile theme. But i need some of them to be rendered in custom region for mobile theme.
Tried:

```
mytheme_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  $vars['block']->region = 'my_region';
}
```

$my_region variable in my page.tpl.php is empty for some reason. The block has content and region is defined and valid. 
What's the solution to switch block position? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it really required to display them like this?

Add a block using a custom module and hook_block() in my_region.

Display all the blocks content using custom php code inside depending the mobile theme conditions from the module itself.

if the block is of type view use the code below to print the view content:

```
    

    $view = views_get_view('view name');
    $view->set_display('block_1'); //or the block id in the view
    $view_block = $view->execute_display('block_1', array()); 
    //pass any arguments if any in the second argument
    print $view_block['content'];
```

if it is of type block only, use:

```
    $block = module_invoke('module_name["block" for blocks created from web interface]', 'block', 'view', 'delta');

    print $block['content'];
```

Let me know if this is confusing.